# Vertx3 - Return a value from a JDBC connection? (sql db).

Tags: java, asynchronous, jdbc, vert.x

I have an interface with a single method that returns "config" Object.

I want to utilize interface this in Android and Vertx3 environments.

```
Config retrieveConfig(String authCreds);
```

I'm trying to implement this in a vertx program, utilizing the JDBC client from it, but I'm running into issues.

```
jdbcClient.getConnection(sqlConnResult -> 
 //checks for success
 sqlConnResult.result().query(selectStatement, rows -> {
     //get result here, want to return it as answer to interface.
     //seems this is a "void" method in this scope.
});
```

Is this interface even possible with Vertx async code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Async programming` you can't really return your value to the caller, because this would then be a blocking call - one of the main things `async programming` seeks to remove. This is why in `Vertx` a lot of methods return `this` or `void`.

Various paradigms exist as alternatives:

- `Vert.x` makes extensive use of the `Handler<T>` interface where the `handler(T result)` method will be executed with the result.
- `Vert.x 3` also has support for the `Rx Observable`. This will allow you to return an `Observable<T>` which will emit the result to `subscribers` once the `async task` has completed.
- Also, there is always an option to return `Future<T>` which, once the async task has completed will contain the result. Although `Vert.x` doesn't really use this very much.

So you're probably going to find it difficult to have a `common interface` like this for `blocking` and `non-blocking api`. `Vertx` offers nice and easy ways to [run blocking code](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#executeBlocking-io.vertx.core.Handler-boolean-io.vertx.core.Handler-) but I don't think that is a good solution in your case.

Personally, I would have a look at [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). There is support for [Rx  on Android](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module), and has been well adopted in `Vertx 3` - with almost every API call having a [Rx equivalent](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/).

Moving from:

```
Config retrieveConfig(String authCreds);
```

to

```
Observable<Config> retrieveConfig(String authCreds);
```

would give you the ability to have a common interface and for it to work on both `Android` & `Vert.x`. It would also give the added benefit of not having to stray into callback hell which `Rx` seeks to avoid.

Hope this helps,

Comment: is it possible to implement the RxJava/reactive implementation without changing the underlying system? can you mix?

Comment: @Zerkz I don't quite understand. Maybe you could update your question with examples, or start a new question and post the link here.

Comment: nm, I think I was able to answer it. Thanks for your help Will!

Comment: Just as an update, I was able to find a solution using Observable, and then transforming it into a blocking observable (making it synchronous).